# Downloading byte array from Spring Boot to Vue frontend

Tags: java, arrays, image, spring-boot, vue.js

I have the following functions, I am trying to read a string from my MongoDB database which is an image decode it and send it to my Vue frontend to be downloaded.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/signature/{signatureId}", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
public byte[] downloadSignature(String signatureId) {
        Signature signature = routeRepository.findBySignature(signature);

        byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(signature.getSignature().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));


        // This try-catch just saves the signature locally for testing
        // This works successfully so I know there isn't an issue with the byte array
        try {
            Files.write(bytes, new File("signature.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
        headers.setContentLength(bytes.length);
        headers.setCacheControl(CacheControl.noCache().getHeaderValue());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(bytes, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

On my Vue frontend, I have the following

```
  async downloadSignature(context, payload) {
    await Route.downloadSignature(context.rootState.User.user, payload)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(
          new Blob([data], { type: "image/png" })
        );
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute("download", "signature.png");
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
      })
      .catch(() => {
        Message.error("Something went wrong, please try again.");
      });
  }
```

Everything works successfully but when the file downloads there is an issue with the file and I cannot open it successfully

[image: cannot open .png file]

Comment: You are Base64 decoding the image. Why? Then it's no longer an image

Comment: Guess I should have made that more clear, the image is coming from an android application where I am base64 encoding it so I can send it in the body of a post request to my Spring boot server

Comment: Sp of you are calling this URL in the browser is then a image dispalyed?

Comment: Why not have a direct link (`<a href="/signature/userSignatureId">Download</a>`) in your Vue application, and let the browser do the rest? If the image then is displayed inline, you might need to set the Content-Disposition to get the download file dialog.

Comment: I dont want to display the image, I just want the user to be able to click a button and  download the image

Answer (score 0):

With Axios, you need to specify in the request headers that the response type is a blob

Like so

```
Vue.axios.get(resource, { responseType: "blob" });
```

Pretty poor documentation on this.