# Handle Byte Array in Vue

Tags: java, arrays, file, vue.js, xls

I'm new in Vue and now trying to handle an bytearray as an .xls file

For now i have an issue that the file looks like
[broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDCfq.png)

If i'm saving it as file at server side, data looks fine and nothing going wrong

Server side:

```
    Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Payments");
    for (int i = 0; i < payments.size(); i++) {
        Payment payment = payments.get(i);
        Row row = sheet.createRow(i);

        ...(adding a lot of data)
    }

    try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        wb.write(bos);
        wb.close();
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }
```

Vue side:

```
axios.post(myRequestAndData)
    .then(resp => {
                var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([resp.data]));
                var fileLink = document.createElement('a');
                fileLink.href = fileURL;
                fileLink.setAttribute('download', 'file.xls');
                document.body.appendChild(fileLink);
                fileLink.click();
```

So how can i handle my ByteArray data to create a file in the right way?
Thanks anyway

Comment: What is the type of resp.data?

Comment: @JoshuaAngnoe responseType:"blob". saw it in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61461094/downloading-byte-array-from-spring-boot-to-vue-frontend

Comment: Have you tried `var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(resp.data));` instead of `new Blob([resp.data])`

Comment: @JoshuaAngnoe nope, but after doing this and rolling back, with only ' responseType:"blob" ' it started work correctly. idk why, but thank you anyway :D

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding `,{responseType:"blob"}` at `axios.post/get` options

Thanks @JoshuaAngnoe for help!